# How can I actually use Maxwell's equations to solve an electromagnetism problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I studied Maxwell's equations, but when it comes to problem solving my teacher never actually used them, so I was wondering if and when do they come useful?
For example, if I have an empty infinite cylinder with radius $R$ and a current $I$ along its surface, is there a way I can use Maxwell equations to find the field $B$ along its axis?

If not, can someone give me an example of when I can?

Comment: In real life problem, usually with difficulty!

Comment: If you ever used Coulomb's law, Gauss's law, Ampere's law, or Faraday's law in your class, then you were using Maxwell's equations to solve problems.

Comment: the antenna in your cell-phone is designed by solving *numerically* the full set of Maxwell's equations specialized for the material, see a few programs listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EM_simulation_software

Comment: Maxwell equations tend to be presented in the differential form (4 equations for divergence and curl of fields), but any physical problem need also the boundary conditions and sometimes constitutive equations.

You can solve the problem that you asked with Maxwell equations (the surface current will create a discontinuity in $H$ field due to boundary conditions). But you might need some extra mathematics to solve the differential equations, depending on the level of the course (using the Maxwell equations to solve any problem is usually covered in electrodynamics, not electromagnetism).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first Maxwell's Equation problem I encountered that didn't rely directly on Coulomb's Law or Gauss' Law.

Suppose you have a grounded, uncharged conducting sphere in a uniform electric field. What is the electric field induced by the applied field?

Without loss of generality, we can assume the applied field is $\vec{E_0}=E_0\hat{z}$.

There is no charge, so $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=0$. There is no magnetic field, so $\nabla \times \vec{E}=0.$ By a theorem of vector calculus, an irrotational vector field, i.e. a field with curl of zero, it may be represented as a gradient of a scalar field. This allows us to combine the two equations for the electric field. First by the curl equation, $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$. We plus that into the divergence equation, $-\nabla^2V=0.$

This final equation in $V$ is a form of Laplace's Equation.

Since our conductor is a sphere, we can take advantage of spherical symmetry and use the Laplacian in the form it takes in spherical coordinates:

$$\nabla^2 V=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial r})+\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2{\phi}}\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{1}{r^2\sin{\phi}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}(\sin \phi\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi})$$

Because of symmetry, we expect the middle term to be zero. Using separation of variables we find that V has a general solution:

$V=A_1+B_1/r+C_1r\cos{\phi}+D_1\frac{\cos{\phi}}{r^2}$.

There are more terms not applicable here.

We break the problem up between $V_{in}$ inside the sphere and $V_{out}$. Since the electric field inside the conductor is zero, V is a constant, since the electric field is the derivative of the potential. V is a constant throughout the sphere, including its surface. It's grounded and we are free to set the potential to any constant we like. So e are free to set $V_{in}=0$.

The boundary conditions of Maxwell's Equations for the electric field tells us that the potential V is continuous through a material boundary. The normal component of the electric field is discontinuous with that discontinuity proportional to the surface charge density.

Now let our V be the potential outside of the sphere. Far away, we want our electric field to be $E_0\hat{z}$. This requires $C_1=-E_0$. $B_1$ is a term associated with net charge in some region of space. But we have no charge, so $B_1$=0. $A_1$ is an arbitrary constant we can set to zero. Finally we need to solve for D. Since we have $V=0$ on the surface of the sphere and the sphere has a radius of $r=R$ we have:

$$0=-E_0R\cos{\phi}+\frac{D_1\cos{\phi}}{R^2}$$.

So $D_1=E_0R^3$

So outside of the sphere, $V=-E_0r\cos\phi+\frac{E_0R^3\cos{\phi}}{r^2}$

Now the negative gradient of the potential is the electric field. The component of the field normal to the surface is the derivative of V with respect to r.

$E_r=E_0\cos{\phi}+2E_0\cos{phi}=3E_0\cos{\phi}$ . By the boundary condition due to Gauss' Law, we have that $\sigma=\epsilon_0 E_r$. So $\sigma=3\epsilon_0\cos{\phi}$.

$\sigma$ is the induced surface charge density which produces an induced dipole field given by the second term of the potential.

Integrate $\sigma$ over the surface and you get zero since there is no total charge, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are four Maxwell Equations. Two refer to Electric Fields and the other two refer to Magnetic Fields. 
Below, I am listing one of each and providing you with an application and a sample question for each. If you wish to see similar ones for the third and fourth equations, please ask.

The symbols used are: **E** stands for Electric Field and **B** stands for Magnetic Field.
Q stands for quantity of charge.
eZ stands for "epsilon zero" where (1/(4 pi eZ) = K, Coulomb Constant.
K' is the magnetic constant.

Equation 1: the closed surface integral of E dotted with an element of area equals the Charge per eZ. The dot product of E and dA is a measure of the electric flux (lines of force).
Another way of stating this law: electric lines of force emanate outward from positive charges and inward to negative charges.

Q-1: determine the electric field strength and the closed electric flux at 0.5 meters from a +3 micro-coulomb of charge.
A-1: using Maxwell's equation, we can determine the E-strength at 0.5 meters using:
E = K Q / R^2. This would equal: 1.08 E 5 N/C OUTWARD.
Again using Maxwell's Equation, we can determine the electric flux by:
E A = (1.08 E 5)(4 pi R^2) = 3.39 E 5 N-m^2/C

Equation 2: the closed surface integral of B dotted with dA is zero.
Putting it another way: magnetic flux lines do not begin or end.

Q-2: describe with reasons, the shape of B due to a current in an infinitely long wire.

A-2: the shape would be circular because Maxwell's Equation hints at the absence of start and end of magnetic lines of force.
Addendum: a) the right hand screw-rule will determine the circle; b) the strength of the field at a distance (d) from the wire equals 2 K' I / d.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell's equations are what are known as *partial differential equations* (PDEs).  They tell you that various derivatives of the fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ must be related to each other, and to the charge density $\rho$ and current density $\vec{J}$, in certain ways.  For example, in the case where everything is static (no $t$ dependence), the equations are
\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} & \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} &= 0 \\ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} &= 0 & \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} &= \mu_0 \vec{J}
\end{align}
If, for whatever reason, you were given the problem "find the charge density $\rho$ and current density $\vec{J}$ that create some given fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$", you could take the appropriate derivatives and find $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ immediately.  This would be a case in which you could apply Maxwell's equations directly.

Usually, though, we're interested in the inverse problem:  given $\rho(\vec{r})$ and $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$, what are $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$?  This means you need to "solve" these partial differential equations.  Solving PDEs is a huge, messy field, and there's not a single one-size-fits-all approach to finding solutions for PDEs.  But in the case of Maxwell's equations, there are known techniques.  Specifically, if you give me $\rho(\vec{r})$, Maxwell's equations for $\vec{E}$ will be obeyed if
$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \iiint \frac{\rho(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|^2} dV,
$$
and if you give me $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$, Maxwell's equations for $\vec{B}$ will be obeyed if
$$
\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \iiint \frac{\vec{J}(\vec{r}') \times (\vec{r} - \vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|^3} dV.
$$
You may recognize these as Coulomb's Law and the Biot-Savart Law, respectively.  It is possible to prove that no matter what $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ are, the above expressions for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ will satisfy Maxwell's equations.

So, to answer your question:

> I studied Maxwell's equations, but when it comes to problem solving my teacher never actually used them, so I was wondering if and when do they come useful? For example, if I have an empty indefinite cylinder with radius R and a current i along its surface, is there a way I can use Maxwell equations to find the field B along its axis?

Strictly speaking, you don't use Maxwell's equations to solve such problems directly.  Rather, you use known methods for finding solutions to Maxwell's equations:  namely, Coulomb's Law and the Biot-Savart Law.  When you do these integrals, you will be guaranteed to find something that obey's Maxwell's equations.

---

[Footnote:  All of this can be extended to the case where $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ depend on time as well.  However, [the equations to solve for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ in this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) are much, much more complicated and are rarely encountered in an introductory E&M course.  Even in upper-level electrodynamics courses, it is more typical to solve for the potentials $V$ and $\vec{A}$ instead.]

Answer (score 0):

Any B-field must have cylindrical symmetry in your problem. i.e. It could run parallel to the axis of the cylinder of it could circulate around that axis. It can't radiate radially away from the axis because one of Maxwell's laws say $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$.

Because there is no current density in the cylinder, then from static version of Ampere's law: 
$$\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J} =0,$$
you know that any B-field is curl-free.

What this means, is that if we switch to the integral form of Ampere's law:
$$ \oint \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0 \int \vec{J} \cdot d\vec{A} = \mu_0 I_{\rm enc}$$
then we can construct a closed circular loop around the axis and deduce that any circulating component of the B-field must be zero, since is encloses no current.

We can also construct a rectangular loop with one edge along the axis of the cylinder and the opposite one still inside the cylinder. Since this also encloses no current, and the radial B-field is zero, then it tells us that if there is a B-field along the axis then it must be uniform inside the cylinder (i.e. $\partial B_z/\partial R =0$.) 
On the other hand we know that currents directed along an axis do not produce magnetic fields along that axis, so there is no "z-component" anywhere inside the cylinder that is produced by currents in the cylinder that travel parallel to the axis.

You actually cannot go any further than this without boundary conditions. The current in the cylinder does not produce any magnetic field inside the cylinder, but that does not preclude there being a uniform B-field inside the cylinder (which would still be there when you turned the current off).

The above arguments just use two of Maxwell's equations.